# Оптимизация recyclerView с картинками

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, bitmap

Всем привет. Делаю приложения для редактирования фото  и хочу добаивть стикеры в приложение. Нашел достаточно много стикеров в интернете  но столкнулся с проблемой отображения. Все стикеры тобишь PNG картинки у меня находяться в папке drawable (350 штук) при отображении DialogFragment внутри которого RecyclerView происходит подвисание пока все картинки не отрисуються и потом при скролинге тоже немного подвисает из за большого количества картинок. Я пробовал сжать картинки и уменшить качество

```
 public  Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }
```

Но это значительно  не повлияло на проблему. Как сделать что бы все работало без подвисаний?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще желательно 350  картинок хранить на бекенде и  при необходимости  подгружать  стикеры. В вашем случае если стикеры все таки  хранятся локально, getResizedBitmap не нужно делать  это нагрузка большая ,  руками  сожмите картинки и уже сжатые добавьте в drawables  +  не надо все 350  отдавать RecyclerAdapter ,  используйте пагинацию,   ну и для отображения советую Glide.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Еще обратите внимание на Picasso

Comment: Пагинация врятли повлияет, Recycler на то и Recycler что ему особо нет разницы сколько картинок отображать.

Comment: Пагинация не помогает. если подгрузить больше 20 картинок начинает подвисать

Comment: @JunDev yno7 все правильно написал. Тут без кода адаптера не разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Помог ресайзинг отображаемых фото я сделал это через Piscasso образом:

```
 Picasso.get().load(stickerList[position])
                .resize(80,100)
                .into(holder.imgSticker);
```

Лаги при скроле recyclerview прошли.